# Best way to keep track of progress bar type state when component unmounts and remounts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was rebuilding/refactoring an old web game of mine built with vanilla JS into React + Redux. There is a specific type of button I created which looks like this:

[image]

Some buttons have a large cooldown of minutes.

I have successfully rebuilt the button component with hooks but realized a big issue. There are "tabs" in the game which when clicked, would bring you to a different screen. This means that these buttons would unmount and lose their state.

The way I handled this when I was working on the vanilla JS version was to keep all buttons in an array and through the main logic loop, I would loop through all buttons and update their progress.

```
//some pseudocode

const gameTick = 30

const buttons = [
  {
    name: 'chop tree',
    duration: 2000 // milliseconds,
    currentDuration: 1230,
    ...
  }, {...}
]

// gameLoop gets fired every 30milliseconds
const gameLoop = () => {
  buttons.forEach(btn => {
    if (btn.currentDuration < btn.duration) {
      btn.currentDuration += gameTick
    }
  })
}

setInterval(gameLoop, gameTick)
```

I would then calculate the percentage and set the width of the progress bar to it.

Using React + Redux though, I can store the buttons into the state but how would I go about handling un-mounts? If a button gets unmounted while in progress, it still needs to be updating in the background so when a user goes back to the tab, the button would be further along or maybe even finished.

I don't see how I could have this information in the reducer while constantly updating the state and passed into the button component.

Another possible idea I had to handle this is to store the timestamp when I change tabs, then when I switch back to the tab with the buttons, I would calculate the time difference and add it up. The problem with this method is you would have to switch to the correct tab to complete something.

Any ideas?